# how can i delete a permission from a group

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a small project using Django / Rest Framework, and now i would like to add soem permissions / Groups.

I would like to know how can i add and delete a permission from a group i already did some research on Google and here i found only how to add but i'm steel looking for a way to delete a permission from a group,

this is what i found :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from api.models import Project
new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='new_group')
# Code to add permission to group ???
ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Project)

# Now what - Say I want to add 'Can add project' permission to new_group?
permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_add_project',
                                   name='Can add project',
                                   content_type=ct)
new_group.permissions.add(permission)
```

Can someone explain to me how to delete a permission from a group ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use permissions just like a ManyToManyField.

```py
permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='can_add_project')
new_group.permissions.remove(permission)
```

Comment: Thank you so much,  what if i want to do that using a form checkboxes . which values should i use in my inputs ( should i use just 1 & 0 )  or can_add like that ?

Comment: You can use *id* for the checkbox value and use it for adding and deleting the permissions from that group.

Comment: can you elaborate please :)

Comment: You could put the permission ID as checkbox value and later delete the ids you get from the Form.